# in R: save text file with different separators for each column?

Tags: r, save, separator

Is it possible in R to save a data frame (or data.table) into a textfile that contains different separators for various columns?
For example:
Column1[TAB]Column2[,]Column3 ?

[] indicate the separators, here a TAB and comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `write.table` accepts only one separator.

`MASS::write.matrix` can do the trick:

```
require(MASS)
m <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 3)
write.matrix(m, file = "", sep = c("\\tab", ","), blocksize = 1)
```

returns

```
1\tab5,9
 2\tab 6,10
 3\tab 7,11
 4\tab 8,12
```

but as the documentation of this function does not say that multiple separators are allowed, it may be safer to do it by yourself, just in case the above has some side effects.

For example,

```
seps <- c("\\tab", ",", "\n")
apply(m, 1, function(x, seps) 
  cat(x, file = "", sep = seps, append = TRUE), seps = seps)
```

returns

```
1\tab5,9
2\tab6,10
3\tab7,11
4\tab8,12
```

Be aware that `append` is set to `TRUE`, so if the output file already exists it will be overwritten.

Comment: Setting a default value for the argument 'seps' simplifies a little the code: apply(m, 1, function(x, seps = c("\\tab", ",", "\n")) 
  cat(x, file = "", sep = seps, append = TRUE))

Comment: Thanks! Works (though it takes very long to save a file)