# How to export data into a file with multiple delimiters (" , " and " : ")?

Tags: r, delimiter, write.table

As the question states, I have to export a table consisting of 12 columns. The text file has to be in a format such that the first 10 columns are separated by a comma and the final columns are separated by a colon.

Example... 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10:11:12

This is the format the file needs to be delivered in.

Here is the code I'm currently using, but it just spits the data out as just a comma delimited file.

```
write.table(
dataset,
"//example_location/example_file.txt",
sep=",",
na="",
row.names=FALSE,
col.names = FALSE,
quote = FALSE
)
```

When reading the file in, I just opened the text file and did a find & replace to turn the colons into commas to make the import easy, but that doesn't work the other way around.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easiest to paste the final three columns together. Something like `dfNew <- cbind(dataset[, 1:9], paste(dataset[, 10], dataset[, 11], dataset[, 12], sep=":"))`. then use `write.csv`.

Comment: This post tells you how to dow it with the MASS packagehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349527/in-r-save-text-file-with-different-separators-for-each-column

Comment: Thanks @lmo that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the following data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(a=1:10,b=runif(10),c=LETTERS[1:10],d=letters[sample(10)],e=letters[sample(10)])
>df

   a          b   c d e
 1   1 0.06288933 A e a
 2   2 0.87430164 B b e
 3   3 0.75860683 C a h
 4   4 0.50647421 D i f
 5   5 0.63847550 E d c
 6   6 0.70805322 F c i
 7   7 0.17644897 G g g
 8   8 0.04757319 H j j
 9   9 0.19058820 I f b
 10 10 0.70976042 J h d
```

and let's say that we want to save only the character ones:

```
new_df<-data.frame(a=df$a,b=df$b,pasteVals=paste0(df$c,":",df$d,":",df$e))

 head(new_df,3)
 a          b       pasteVals
 1   1 0.06288933     A:e:a
 2   2 0.87430164     B:b:e
 3   3 0.75860683     C:a:h
```

Therefore you can now: `write.csv(new_df,"new.csv",row.names=F)`.